# cycle through a list while skipping elements (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I'm trying to find a way of going through a loop of a single list skipping the first element each time.

so for example, if I have a list:

```
lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

and wish to use a for loop to cycle through all but the first element and stop at an arbitrary point. So if I wish to start at index 1 of lst and advance through a cycle of each element (excluding the first) I can use the following:

```
scd = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
out = []
for i in range (1,14+1):
    if (i%len(lst)) not in scd:
        continue
    else:
        out.append(lst[i%len(lst)])
print(out)
```

it returns a list with only 12 elements:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

The output that I'm trying to get is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2]
```

I know the issue is in using the `continue` in the for loop, but I'm struggling with a workaround that gets me the desired output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. also if there's a more pythonic way of going about this problem, I'm all ears.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you simply want to repeat the same list, right? How about this where you could concatenate lists using `divmod`:

```
num = 14
i,j = divmod(num, len(lst)-1)
out = lst[1:] * i + lst[1:1+j]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2]
```